# Class won't generate g.dart file automatically

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'person_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class PersonModel extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  int personID = UniqueKey().hashCode;

  @HiveField(1)
  String personName = "";

  @HiveField(2)
  double personWeight = 0.0;

  @HiveField(3)
  double personHeight = 0.0;

  @HiveField(4)
  double personBMI = 0.0;

  @HiveField(5)
  bool personHasGoodBMI = false;

  PersonModel();

  PersonModel.create(this.personID, this.personName, this.personWeight,
      this.personHeight, this.personBMI, this.personHasGoodBMI);
}
```

For some reason, when I run `dart run build_runner build`, the `person_model.g.dart` is not generated.

I get no errors, actually it gives me success but the file is nowhere to be found.
It's the first time this happens to me, can I get any explanation?

Comment: Try `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`, sometimes that helps.

Comment: nop, the outcome was exctly the same...

Comment: Do you have a `build.yaml` file restricting which folders are built, and which builders can run in which folders?

Comment: You have included `hive_generator` as a dev dependency, right?

Comment: Yes I have, and there're no build restrictions

Comment: I also ran flutter clean, flutter pub get and dart run all over again, still nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255260/discussion-between-pgs-and-caio).

Comment: Please add the output from `dart run build_runner build --verbose`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i solved this issue by changing your code like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'person_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 100)
class PersonModel {
  @HiveField(0)
  int personID = UniqueKey().hashCode;

  @HiveField(1)
  String personName = "";

  @HiveField(2)
  double personWeight = 0.0;

  @HiveField(3)
  double personHeight = 0.0;

  @HiveField(4)
  double personBMI = 0.0;

  @HiveField(5)
  bool personHasGoodBMI = false;

  PersonModel(this.personID, this.personName, this.personWeight,
      this.personHeight, this.personBMI, this.personHasGoodBMI);
}
```

For generate the .g.dart files use `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

make sure that you fille is named as person_model.dart